# Getting error while configuring s3cmd

Tags: s3cmd

Configuring `s3cmd` via `s3cmd --configure` is failing even after providing the correct access credentials. The error that is thrown up is `ERROR: S3 error: Access Denied`. I am using version 1.5.2, downloaded via `pip`.

The `Default Region` is set to US, but I don't live there. Is this causing any problems, since my clock is set to a different timezone?

PS: Those who have written about configuring `s3cmd`, didn't get to choose `Default Region`. May be this was included in more recent versions.

Answer (score 0):

Run with --debug and see what it tells you.  Perhaps the access key you are trying to use does not have ListAllMyBuckets permission (which is required)?  You can edit your config file to specify a different region after the fact.  The same key works for all regions except cn-north-1 and govcloud, so getting it to work in US region means it should work for all others.